# Why do some prometheus metric values return +Inf

Tags: time-series, prometheus

Occasionally when I query prometheus using the api endpoint one or more of the metric values will be +Inf.   What does +Inf mean and what causes a metric value to be +Inf ?

[image: Inf+ metric values]

Additional info:

This data is coming from a Gauge metric type

The query is a simple sum query. ie. sum(my_metric)

Answer (score 4):

+Inf stands for a positive infinite number, it would be easier if you would pass what are you measuring, but most probably you're getting this value because if dividing by 0.

Anyway, it's a normal value of float64.

Comment: It's not really "normal" value. Yes IEEE 754 supports it, but, for example, JSON does not.

Comment: But here the JSON values are strings, so it doesn't matter. 
The conversion is handled on the Prometheus side.

Comment: Then it should probably handle other IEEE 754 values, like negative zero, signaling/quiet NaNs etc.

Comment: This one I cannot guarantee, I did not check Prometheus docs/implementation in a while :P